# Calculate checked values inside Angular Material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

There is an [example of Angular Material table with checkboxes](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nlkrbdboavb) which is exactly what I want to use in my app. My issue is - that I want to calculate total value of the checked rows. For example, total sum of the Weight in current example.

Is it possible, and what do I need to add in the code to make it happen? Couldn't find any similar examples online...

Answer (score 0):

From the example you provided , you can get the selected/checked  items of Material Table by using:

```
this.selection.selected
```

It will give you the checked items from the table.

To find the total you can use the code snippet below using reduce .Add  the following line to the function in which you want to calculate the total weight

```
let totalWeight = this.selection.selected.reduce((acc , val)=> acc+ val.weight , 0)
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.